# Android Convert String to Timestamp

Tags: android, date

RSS feed puts pubDate as following:

```
Fri, 07 Aug 2015 08:08:31 GMT
```

How do I convert it to a `Timestamp` in `Android`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
String str_date="Fri, 07 Aug 2015 08:08:31 GMT";
Date localTime = null;
try {
    localTime = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",Locale.getDefault()).parse(str_date);
    System.out.println("TimeStamp is " +localTime.getTime());
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean this?

```
try{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(yourString);
    Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly the format the question implies.

Comment: That's not exactly the format the question implies.